# for loop in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to run the emails to 10 different users, i have made variable $friendsEmails into an array which contains 10 different emails, however looks that it will duplicate 10 for each email thats 10x10. am i doing something wrong?

```
  for($i =0; $i<11; $i++){

    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);

    $mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);

    $mail->Subject    = "We wish you a merry Christmas";

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAddress($friendsEmails[$i], $friendsNames[$i]);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }

       }
```

Comment: If your array is zero indexed, then you want that loop condition to be $i<10 - if you leave it at 11, you'll loop an extra time.  Otherwise I don't see any problem.  Is the Program echoing "Message sent!" 100 times?  Is there any other code in your script?

Comment: yup its give me 100X emails

Answer (score 2):

No wonder you are sending multiple emails because in every iteration of your for loop you are just adding new addresses. Use `PHPMailer::clearAllRecipients()` to remove data from the previous iteration before adding a new email address.

```
for($i =0; $i<11; $i++){
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email,$name);
    $mail->Subject    = "We wish you a merry Christmas";
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->AddAddress($friendsEmails[$i], $friendsNames[$i]);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
    $mail->clearAllRecipients(); // Clear all recipient types(to, bcc, cc).
}
```

Comment: If there are a lot of emails, would this not kill the request or request times out ?

Comment: If configured maximum execution time is too low eventually it will which is why it has to be increased (if possible) or this script needs to be implemented through some kind of queuing system which will allow the script to be triggered with timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to put the e-mail addresses in key value pairs in an array. So the key is the name of your friend and the value the e-mail address. And use an foreach loop to iterate over the whole array without having to determine how many items are in the array.

Oh and reinstantiate your mail object every loop, to not have it send each last e-mail as well (don't know for sure, but that's what could be happening)

Try something like this:

```
$friendsEmails = array('name' => 'email_address');

foreach($friendsEmails as $name => $email) {

    $mail = new Mailer();

    $mail->SetFrom($name);

    $mail->AddReplyTo($name);

    $mail->Subject = "We wish you a merry Christmas";

    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at the end of every iteration you should clean your `mail` object.

Another option is to instantiate one different mail class at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: I found out that i start with $body .=  which is the starting point where i should not start with, I should use normal $body = "my html"